# Transfer pseudocode to Swift results in different outputs

Tags: swift, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I would like to transfer the following pseudo code from my script to Swift. Unfortunately I get a different result with my code than in the script...

Pseudo code, result = 101010100100101111011010:

```
generator = 1111111111111010000001001
data = 1000110101000000011010 1110010000001000000001 0101101001100111100011 0101001101001000100000[000000000000000000000000] # append 24 zero bits

FOR i FROM 0 TO (112-24):
     IF data[i] IS 1:
          data[i:i+24] = data[i:i+24] XOR generator

remainder = data[-24:]

# final result: 101010100100101111011010, or AA4BDA in hexadecimal
```

swift code, result = 010001011010110000110000:

```
let binaryString = "1000110101000000011010111001000000100000000101011010011001111000110101001101001000100000000000000000000000000000"
let generator = 0b1111111111111010000001001

var binaryArray = [Int]()
for number in binaryString {
    binaryArray.append(Int(String(number))!)
}

for i in 0..<88 {
    if binaryArray[i] == 1 {
        var value = ""
        for element in binaryArray[i..<i+24] {
            value = value.appending(String(element))
        }
        let number = Int(value, radix: 2)!
        
        let berechnung = number ^ generator
        let berechnungString = Array(String(berechnung, radix: 2))
        
        var counter = 0
        for y in i..<i+24 {
            binaryArray[y] = Int(String(berechnungString[counter]))!
            counter = counter + 1
        }
        
    }
}

print(binaryArray.suffix(24))
```

What's wrong with my Swift code?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Scott Thompson Not really, I need this code to solve another task inside of my thesis.